# Play Large Number Of Media Files

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I might have around 50 different media files to be played in my activity. Currently I have made just 2 **MediaPlayer** objects for 2 things to be played in my app but making 50 different objects of **Media Player** for different things is not sounding right to me. So, I thought of making a single WAV file and playing the respective voices in respective time interval.

Question : Any other options I have? Is the idea of creating a single merged WAV file correct?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you are doing with these media files in your app? _(For example: are these sound effects files?)_

Comment: these are wav files which are to be played when user click buttons .. like if there are 50 buttons so 50 different voices will be played..

Comment: Is it possible to use just one MediaPlayer object for all 50+ sounds?

Comment: That is what I am trying to say. One MediaPlayer object poiting to one big WAV file and different sounds being played @respective time intervals

Comment: That sounds like "sprite slicing"... one question though: what happens when you need to update a certain sound inside your big WAV file?

Comment: That i never have to do. No such thing has to be done. No updation is required. So, back to square one, this method which looks like sprite slicing is fine or there is any other method which can be useful in this situation?